# What does `~` do?

Tags: command-line, directory, chmod

I saw ~ [here](http://www.rroij.com/open-access/porting-and-bsp-customization-of-android43-on-imx6-based-custom-hardware-platform.php?aid=44219) before the path of repository.

```
chmod a+x ~/bin/repo
```

What does `~` do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is short hand for `$HOME` or `/home/your_current_user`

I advise you avoid using it in scripts or with sudo as results can be unexpected.

You can also specify a user with `~user` rather than `/home/user`

Basically save typing, usually works, but can yield unexpected results in scripts.

For the gory details see http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html

Those pages cover most anything you want to know about bash and cure insomnia ;p

> home directory [tilde]. This corresponds to the $HOME internal
>   variable. ~bozo is bozo's home directory, and ls ~bozo lists the
>   contents of it. ~/ is the current user's home directory, and ls ~/
>   lists the contents of it.

Note "tab completion" also saves typing. start typing part of a path or command and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>

cd /ho<kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>

Helpful for commands and long paths other than ~

Again see http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tabexpansion.html